# Why unable to update html img src with response from ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have some html that includes a *table* with some *tr* rows and each row has a *td* element containing an *img* element. Elsewhere on the page I have an ajax method that sends a url to the server, server then saves this locally and returns the location back.

I then try to update the src attribute element for each img element with the new url, bu nothing is updated. My debugging alert calls shows that the image elements are found and the correct location is returned, at a loss to know what Im doing wrong.

**Html**

```
  <table class="edittable" id="ARTWORK_TABLE">
    <tr>
        <th class="tableheading verysmallinputfield" style="position:relative">
            <label>
                #
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading verysmallinputfield" style="position:relative">
            <label>
                Replace
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading verylargeinputfield" style="position:relative">
            <label>
                Filename
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading mediuminputfield" style="position:relative">
            <label>
                Artwork
            </label>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="menu_artwork1">
        <td class="tableheading">
            0
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>
                E:\Music\Tango in the Night\02 - Seven Wooooooonders.WAV
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/51sjc9qpk4oqFYZdroM04w==_thumbnail.jpg" width="32px" height="32px" title="600 x 585">
            <label>
                600 x 585
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="menu_artwork2">
        <td class="tableheading">
            1
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>
                E:\Music\Tango in the Night\03 - Everywhere.WAV
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/51sjc9qpk4oqFYZdroM04w==_thumbnail.jpg" width="32px" height="32px" title="600 x 585">
            <label>
                600 x 585
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
.........
```

**Javascript Ajax function**

```
function sendFormData(urls)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/editsongs.update_artwork', false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
    xhr.send(urls[0]);
    var images = document.getElementById("ARTWORK_TABLE").getElementsByTagName("img");
    alert("Found img"+images.length);
    for(image in images)
    {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        image.src = xhr.responseText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing

```
image.src = xhr.responseText;
```

to

```
images[image].src = xhr.responseText;
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in for more details

Comment: Thanks that works, seem like my for loop is wrong then should I be using a  for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) type loop then really.

Answer (score 1):

Try to `console.log` the `images` collection and then each image in your [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

You can also `console.log(typeof images)` to find out that it is actually an object and that explains the unexpected values you find in each `image` of your `for...in` loop.

Since this is the case, you could use a normal `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  console.log(images[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `for ... in` syntax, you will need to refer to the property `image` (each `img` element) on your HTML collection of `img` elements:

```
for (var image in images) {
    images[image].src = xhr.responseText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is a bit confusing I have changed to use a normal for loop

Comment: I understand. Didn't want to suggest "just use a different loop" but rather make corrections to your original choice. Definitely use what makes to you though!